# MS Access Date range filtering displaying no records only for a certain range

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I Do have a form with a sub-form (continuous form) on which I would like to apply a date range filter. The thing is that it works partially.

I am using a simple piece of VBA that seem to be THE method. I am using two controls (start & End) and a button to apply the filter.

He is my code sample

```
With Me.Sub_Desi_Schedule.Form
    .Filter = "[Task_End] " & " BETWEEN " & "#" & DateStart & "#" & " AND " & "#" & DateEnd & "#"
    .FilterOn = True
```

And it works fine except when I pick a date range with a value in the last days of the month (as starting period) AND any values within the first week of the next month (as ending period). 
Results are blanks even if there is values AND no error message of any kind to help me trouble shooting.

I thought that it could have been something with the date format. I tried to force it to DDMMYYY. No effect and It had the same strange behavior.

And for any other ranges picked later on the month, it works fine...

Does anyone here had this problem before? Is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're right that the problem is due to date format.

Examine the completed filter string the code creates.  Do that by using a variable to hold it.  Then you can use `Debug.Print` to see it, and later assign the variable to the form's `.Filter` property.

```vb
Dim strFilter As String
With Me.Sub_Desi_Schedule.Form
    strFilter = "[Task_End] BETWEEN #" & DateStart & "# AND #" & DateEnd & "#"
    Debug.Print strFilter ' <- view this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
    .Filter = strFilter
    .FilterOn = True
End With
```

You can avoid problems due to date format by using the unambiguous *yyyy-m-d* format for those Date/Time values.

```vb
strFilter = "[Task_End] BETWEEN " & Format(DateStart, "\#yyyy-m-d\#") & " AND " & Format(DateEnd, "\#yyyy-m-d\#")
```

I added the `#` delimiters within the `Format` expressions.  But you don't need to do it that way; I think this should work as well ...

```vb
strFilter = "[Task_End] BETWEEN #" & Format(DateStart, "yyyy-m-d") & "# AND #" & Format(DateEnd, "yyyy-m-d") & "#"
```

Comment: No reason to assume. The (missing) date format is the problem.

Comment: HansUp, you nailed it ! It works like a freakin charm...

I guess that from now on the only date format to use in ANY vba will be the unambiguous yyyy-m-d...

It's a beautiful day today : I've learned something useful.

Thanks to you !!